# Which AsyncTask should I use behind SERIAL_EXECUTOR in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am retrieving already created data in all user controls. And there are 3 Spinners so I am using `SERIAL_EXECUTOR` to execute it one by one. But now, issue is that, one `Spinner` retrieves data based on another `Spinner`.
So which `AsyncTask` executor should I use for that `Spinner` by which It can load its data although `SERIAL_EXECUTOR` is going on.
In short, I want to know which `AsyncTask` should I use which will execute that Task even though `SERIAL_EXECUTOR` is in process.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question? What prevents you from using the `SERIAL_EXECUTOR` which by the way is the default for all AsyncTasks since Honeycomb?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute an `AsyncTask` parallel to another one then you can use `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` like this:

```
AsyncTask task = new SomeAsyncTask();
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

But I warn you that this might not work as good as you might like. If the `AsyncTasks` you are executing perform quite a bit of work on their own than executing them in parallel will slow them down considerably. If possible, try to execute tasks serially, only execute in parallel if you absolutely have to. If you need to load data which is dependent on some other kind of data consider doing it in one big `AsyncTask` instead of splitting the work to to `AsyncTasks`. Always try to keep the amount of `AsyncTasks` or `Threads` to a minimum. The fewer you have the faster your app will load.

Comment: Could you please give any official reference for your last statement: " The fewer you have the faster your app will load."?